# What is the correct HTML tag for content that has changed (but not added/deleted)?

Tags: html

I know I can use `<ins>` to identify added content and `<del>` to identify deleted content. But what should I use to mark content that has changed, without further details on what was added or deleted?

For example:

Providing both added and deleted content (`del`/`ins`):

```html
Cost: <del>$10</del><ins>$20</ins>.
```

Providing only new content, what to use to indicate that it has changed?

```html
Cost: <?>$20</?>.
```

I thought about `<mark>`, but that does not quite work as `<mark>` adds semantics not intended by the original author, but in this case I do intend to mark it as changed when authoring.

Comment: Providing both added and deleted content (`del` / `ins`) is essentially what MS Word and company do when you're tracking changes, so that's not a bad idea.

Comment: taking from almost ANY git, you remove a line and add a line. the closest HTML tag though: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-s-element PLEASE CHECK THE NOTE!!!

Answer (score 0):

> The s element represents contents that are no longer accurate or no
>   longer relevant.

From https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-s-element

```html
<p>Buy our Iced Tea and Lemonade!</p>
<p><s>Recommended retail price: $3.99 per bottle</s></p>
<p><strong>Now selling for just $2.99 a bottle!</strong></p>
```

> The s element is not appropriate when indicating document edits; to
>   mark a span of text as having been removed from a document, use the
>   del element.